# Should I have a single table to source the drop-down values or create multiple tables for each drop down

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have multiple drop down box (around 23) on a single  web page, these drop downs get their values from SQL database. Should I have a single table to source the drop-down values or create multiple tables for each drop down.

Should I create a table with field id for each drop down and all permitted values for the field or create 22 tables with 2 to 5 values in each table.

e.g. Gender: has 2 values male/female would it make sense to have table for gender?

Comment: Thats a design question only you can answer. There are pros and cons for each approach.

Comment: @DaleK its MySQL

Answer (score 0):

In my project, we have single table used to store such options on GUI. There, we have stored such information related to all screens. Columns of table is something like below :

```
Optiontype - possible values like gender
Optiontype_Code - possible values like M, F
Code _Description -  possible values Male, Female
```

You can add more columns to table as per your requirement for fast retrieval of data like screen id or something.

Comment: Note that option is a reserved word in mysql

Comment: Mine was on db2. Thanks for pointing it out. I just changed it.